# What does simple JSON object format look like in RDF and OWL/WOL?

Tags: json, rdf, semantic-web, owl

I have the following JSON objects...

```
var people = [
  {"LName": "Smith", "FName": "Jane", "Gender": "Female", "Age": 20},
  {"LName": "Doe", "FName": "John", "Gender": "Male", "Age": 40},
  {"LName": "Smith", "FName": "Mary", "Gender": "Female", "Age": 29}
];
```

Note that the above representation is simply First Normal Form (1NF), representing three (3) denormalized objects, where each would be a row in a "People" table that has column names "LName", "FName", "Gender" and "Age".

Given the above, what would the above look like after being translated/converted to OWL/WOL?

Comment: It could look like any number of things.  It's kind of like asking what it would look like if stored in a database.  You *might* have a single People table with columns for LName, FName, Gender, and Age, or you might have a table for Gender with columns LName, Fname, and (gender) Value and a table for Age with columns LName, Fname, and (age) Value, with (LName,Fname) in each of those being a key.  There's no "right answer" for this.

Comment: WOL is the accurate representation for "Web Ontology Language", although they started using "OWL" for lack of a better acronym.  If there is no standard representation for the above, how would Systems A and B transmit lists of people to System C (using OWL), if A and B can generate different representations?

Comment: I've been working worth OWL for a number of years, and I've never seen it abbreviated WOL. It was OWL 12 years ago in the [initial specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-features/), and the [OWL FAQ](https://www.w3.org/2003/08/owlfaq) says that the working  group decided on OWL (which would be before it was finished). Have you seen it called WOL somewhere?

Comment: There are lots of ways that it could be represented, just like the are lots of ways it could be represented in JSON. OWL let's you define the properties and classes that you'll use, kind of like a JSON schema language might let you specify what property names you'll use in JSON. The difference between plain schema languages and OWL is based on description logics and gives you a semantics for reasoning.

Comment: For those who have been dealing with it since it's inception, it was WOL before it was OWL, which was changed in the 2001/2002 timeframe (http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-webont-wg/2001Dec/0169.html).

Comment: I do understand that OWL does offer description logics and semantics for reasoning but I'm just looking for a simple way to represent a "set of specific types of things."  If it's not clear, then maybe we have an explanation for why it gets so little adoption and use.

Comment: But it's just like the database analogy.  You could represent that same information in multiple ways in a relational database.  Just because birth databases could be queried and constructed with SQL doesn't mean that there's some single right way of representing that information.  But people certainly do use relational databases.

Comment: In this case, there are definitely some *common* ways that this information could be represented:  you could the FOAF vocabulary, or DBpedia's ontology.  If you want to know how this data would be represented in either of those, that's be pretty straightforward.  But there is never going to be a single, all-purpose, canonical representation for some chunk of data.

Comment: Interesting read about SWRL, WOL, and OWL naming, by the way;  thanks for sharing the link!

Comment: Thanks. I did change the example question to include RDF and I added a note to clarify that the data is 1NF, where each JSON object is a row in a denormalized table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single way to do this.  The same information could be encoded in RDF or OWL in numerous ways.  It all depends on what kind of information you're trying to encode and preserve.  If you just want information about three persons, then you might use the FOAF vocabulary to encode the information.  Or if you want to preserve the JSON semantics, you might use an encoding of JSON structures.  Or you might define an ontology with the properties that you need and encode according to that.  Here's what those first two approaches might look like.  You can obviously come up with others, though.

### In FOAF

If you use the FOAF vocabulary (which isn't strictly OWL, but defines an RDF vocabulary, you might end up with something like this:

#### In N3

```
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

[] a foaf:Person ;
   foaf:firstName "Smith" ;
   foaf:lastName "Jane" ;
   foaf:gender "Female" ;
   foaf:age 20 .

[] a foaf:Person ;
   foaf:firstName "Doe" ;
   foaf:lastName "John" ;
   foaf:gender "Male" ;
   foaf:age 40 .

[] a foaf:Person ;
   foaf:firstName "Smith" ;
   foaf:lastName "Mary" ;
   foaf:gender "Female" ;
   foaf:age 29 .
```

#### In RDF/XML

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/">
  <foaf:Person>
    <foaf:firstName>Smith</foaf:firstName>
    <foaf:lastName>Mary</foaf:lastName>
    <foaf:gender>Female</foaf:gender>
    <foaf:age rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
    >29</foaf:age>
  </foaf:Person>
  <foaf:Person>
    <foaf:firstName>Doe</foaf:firstName>
    <foaf:lastName>John</foaf:lastName>
    <foaf:gender>Male</foaf:gender>
    <foaf:age rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
    >40</foaf:age>
  </foaf:Person>
  <foaf:Person>
    <foaf:firstName>Smith</foaf:firstName>
    <foaf:lastName>Jane</foaf:lastName>
    <foaf:gender>Female</foaf:gender>
    <foaf:age rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
    >20</foaf:age>
  </foaf:Person>
</rdf:RDF>
```

### JSON Encoding

If you want to preserve more of the JSON information, e.g., that you have an array, that it has three elements, etc., you  might do something more like this:

#### In N3

```
prefix json: <urn:json:>

[] a json:Array ;
   json:elements (
     [ json:hasProperty [ json:propertyName "LName" ;
                          json:propertyValue "Smith" ] ,
                        [ json:propertyName "FName" ;
                          json:propertyValue "Jane" ] ,
                        [ json:propertyName "Gender" ;
                          json:propertyValue "Female" ] ,
                        [ json:propertyName "Age" ;
                          json:propertyValue 20 ] ]
     [ json:hasProperty [ json:propertyName "LName" ;
                          json:propertyValue "Dow" ] ,
                        [ json:propertyName "FName" ;
                          json:propertyValue "John" ] ,
                        [ json:propertyName "Gender" ;
                          json:propertyValue "Male" ] ,
                        [ json:propertyName "Age" ;
                          json:propertyValue 40 ] ]
     [ json:hasProperty [ json:propertyName "LName" ;
                          json:propertyValue "Smith" ] ,
                        [ json:propertyName "FName" ;
                          json:propertyValue "Mary" ] ,
                        [ json:propertyName "Gender" ;
                          json:propertyValue "Female" ] ,
                        [ json:propertyName "Age" ;
                          json:propertyValue 29 ] ] 
   ) .
```

#### In RDF/XML

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:json="urn:json:">
  <json:Array>
    <json:elements rdf:parseType="Collection">
      <rdf:Description>
        <json:hasProperty rdf:parseType="Resource">
          <json:propertyName>LName</json:propertyName>
          <json:propertyValue>Smith</json:propertyValue>
        </json:hasProperty>
        <json:hasProperty rdf:parseType="Resource">
          <json:propertyName>FName</json:propertyName>
          <json:propertyValue>Jane</json:propertyValue>
        </json:hasProperty>
        <json:hasProperty rdf:parseType="Resource">
          <json:propertyName>Gender</json:propertyName>
          <json:propertyValue>Female</json:propertyValue>
        </json:hasProperty>
        <json:hasProperty rdf:parseType="Resource">
          <json:propertyName>Age</json:propertyName>
          <json:propertyValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
          >20</json:propertyValue>
        </json:hasProperty>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description>
        <json:hasProperty rdf:parseType="Resource">
          <json:propertyName>LName</json:propertyName>
          <json:propertyValue>Dow</json:propertyValue>
        </json:hasProperty>
        <json:hasProperty rdf:parseType="Resource">
          <json:propertyName>FName</json:propertyName>
          <json:propertyValue>John</json:propertyValue>
        </json:hasProperty>
        <json:hasProperty rdf:parseType="Resource">
          <json:propertyName>Gender</json:propertyName>
          <json:propertyValue>Male</json:propertyValue>
        </json:hasProperty>
        <json:hasProperty rdf:parseType="Resource">
          <json:propertyName>Age</json:propertyName>
          <json:propertyValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
          >40</json:propertyValue>
        </json:hasProperty>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description>
        <json:hasProperty rdf:parseType="Resource">
          <json:propertyName>LName</json:propertyName>
          <json:propertyValue>Smith</json:propertyValue>
        </json:hasProperty>
        <json:hasProperty rdf:parseType="Resource">
          <json:propertyName>FName</json:propertyName>
          <json:propertyValue>Mary</json:propertyValue>
        </json:hasProperty>
        <json:hasProperty rdf:parseType="Resource">
          <json:propertyName>Gender</json:propertyName>
          <json:propertyValue>Female</json:propertyValue>
        </json:hasProperty>
        <json:hasProperty rdf:parseType="Resource">
          <json:propertyName>Age</json:propertyName>
          <json:propertyValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
          >29</json:propertyValue>
        </json:hasProperty>
      </rdf:Description>
    </json:elements>
  </json:Array>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua.  Very helpful.  It's interesting to see how verbose each translated format is, compared to one another.

Comment: @InformationTechnology Well, RDF is a graph based format;  the serialization formats are only important for getting the data from one place to another.  That said, N3/Turtlle is much more human readable/writeable, and it's what I started with, and only translated that to RDF/XML to highlight the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It could take on a number of forms depending on how you want to model your data.

For example, you may decide to use some existing vocabulary or ontology (such as FOAF), or create your own home made ontology - in that case you may choose to define restrictions on the properties involved (e.g. whether functional, their types, etc.), or even provide additional rules to allow different forms of inference when analysing the data (e.g. auto-classify people with "female" gender as belonging to a `Female` class).

In general though, when creating an ontology you have two "sections" that you work with: the terminology (TBox) where you define the various restrictions/classes/properties of the model, and the assertions (ABox) where you instantiate things based on the model.

A bare bones representation (in [Turtle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_(syntax)) syntax) skipping most of the above (except some basic property restrictions), could look like this:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix : <http://foo.bar#> .

# TBox
:Person a owl:Class .

:first_name a owl:DatatypeProperty;
  rdfs:domain :Person;
  rdfs:range xsd:string .

:last_name a owl:DatatypeProperty;
  rdfs:domain :Person;
  rdfs:range xsd:string .

:gender a owl:DatatypeProperty;
  rdfs:domain :Person;
  rdfs:range xsd:string .

:age a owl:DatatypeProperty;
  rdfs:domain :Person;
  rdfs:range xsd:integer .

# ABox

:person_1 a :Person;
  :last_name "Smith;
  :first_name "Jane";
  :gender "female";
  :age 20.

:person_2 a :Person;
  :last_name "Doe;
  :first_name "John";
  :gender "male";
  :age 40.

:person_3 a :Person;
  :last_name "Smith;
  :first_name "Mary";
  :gender "female";
  :age 29.
```

As an example of further modelling, you may decide that `:gender` can only take on the values "female" or "male". An alternative way to define `:gender` in that case would be:

```
:gender a owl:DatatypeProperty;
  rdfs:range  [
    a rdfs:Datatype;
      owl:oneOf ( "Female" "Male")
  ] .
```

I suppose you could also define `gender` to be a [functional](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#FunctionalProperty-def) property (to have only one unique value for each instance of `Person`).

Comment: Are "person_1", "person_2" and "person_3" the equivalent of unique IDs?

Comment: In some way, yes. Every individual/instance in the knowledge base requires a unique identifier/URI.

Comment: @InformationTechnology Those are concrete IRIs, so :person_1 is shorthand for `http://foo.bar#person_1`.  That's "unique" in a sense, but not globally.  I used blank nodes in my examples precisely because there *isn't* another particularly good unique identifier (at least, not without specifying something based on the input data).